How to define variable template and its specialized version in a `.h` file?
I've run into some tricky issues with recursive variable template.
I define variable template with non-type template parameters and its specialization in mymath.h to implement the factorial. Any non-negative integer n can instantiate Factorial as a constant expression multiplied by all integers from 1-n.
The recursive process stop when n reach the 0.
template <int N>
int Factorial = N * Factorial<N-1>;

template <>
int Factorial<0> = 1;

However, mymath.h cannot be included in more than source file since the specialized one Fractial<0> is treated as a GLOBAL symbol and will cause a duplicate definition when linking If I do so.
$ readelf -s file1.cpp | grep "Fractial"

4897: 0000000000000000     8 OBJECT  GLOBAL DEFAULT 1978 _Z9FactorialILm0EE


And I cannot hide it the definition of Fractial<0> in .cpp file as compiler should know when the recursion should stop before n get into negative field.

Variables can also be inline.

@BoP Fine... I just learnt about that.

Don't use templates (structs to do calculations) for this but constexpr functions like this :
// header file
inline constexpr unsigned int factorial(unsigned int n)
{
    if ((n == 1) || (n == 0)) return 1;
    return n * factorial(n - 1);
}

inline constexpr unsigned int factorial3 = factorial(3);

// source file
int main()
{
    static_assert(factorial(3) == 6);
}


Or even use consteval, if possible?

@LernerCpp Yeah if you really want only compile time evaluation
